# Passing an address to a class and from there to its "child-class" by reference in C++

Tags: c++, class, pointers, reference, memory-address

"pointer" holds the address of "Int". I want to pass that address to my given classes by reference:

```
class N {
public:
    N(int &pPointer){   
        std::cout << "Address: " << &(pPointer) <<" \n";
    }
};
class M {
public:
    M(int &pPointer):n(pPointer) {              
       std::cout << "Address: " << &pPointer <<" \n";
    }   
    private:
     N n;
};

int main () {
    int Int = 5;
    int *pointer = &Int;    
    std::cout << "Address: " << pointer <<" \n";
    M m(*pointer);  
     return 0;
}
```

Is this a good practice (since I'm kind of using a reference to a dereferenced pointer)? 
Or is it absolutely horrible? 
I simply want to avoid pointers here. (Although I'm forced to use "*pointer" in the beginning. )

Comment: why are you forced to use `*pointer` in the beginning ? Why not just use `M m(Int);` ?

Comment: Good question! In my project, I want to pass a "global" screen to some render-functions. screen has to be a pointer to a SDL_Surface, because the initial function SDL_SetVideoMode returns a pointer to a SDL_Surface. see here: http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html

Answer (score 1):

It's totally OK to pass by reference instead of passing by pointer to use the abject later, as lon you know the pointer you are using is valid. This allows you to skip the `nullptr` check, because references can't be null.
However if you store a reference, you won't be able to replace the object being referred to, to another. But you can do that with a pointer.
You can, later, take the address of the referenced object, but do you really think you *need* to do that? Because you can use the reference instead

Answer (score 0):

It's ok if you must, but do consider using a constant reference `N(const int& pPointer)` instead in the function parameters. This means you can't change the pointer to point at something else, but you could can still modify the underlying variable value with a dereference.

Also take care if you store the reference as a data member in the class. You could end up with a 'dangling reference' if the object in the caller (an int in your case) goes out of scope.

Comment: This makes no sense for me: a reference is always const, since it can only "reference" something for one time. (Whereas pointers can point to different things during runtime.) And I do want "pPointer" to be able to change "Int".

Comment: Not quite. If a reference is an object (rather than a POD) you can't call non-const functions on that object or modify its member data. For a POD, you can't modify the reference either: e.g. int k = 8; const int& l = k; l = 9; is invalid but int k = 8; int& l = k; l = 9; is fine.

Comment: But as I said: I want pPointer (in your example "l") in class N to be able to change "Int" (in your example "k").