# How can I pass a "global" pointer to a SDL_Surface to a render-function of a class in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, sdl, extern

My following problem is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16604374/passing-an-address-to-a-class-and-from-there-to-its-child-class-by-reference-i).

I want to pass a "global" screen to a render-function of a class. screen has to be a pointer to a SDL_Surface, because the initial function [SDL_SetVideoMode](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/sdlsetvideomode.html) returns a pointer to a SDL_Surface.

Should I pass screen (set up in int main(){}) by reference to the render-function?

```
void renderClass::render (SDL_Surface &screen){...}
```

**Edit:** 
Or should I use a pointer?:

```
void renderClass::render (SDL_Surface *screen){...}
```

Or should I simply use

```
 extern SDL_Surface *screen;
```

in each header-file. (Since I'm using multiple source files)

Or is there any better way? I just want to get rid of pointers.

Comment: Personally, I'm using the first one, passing by reference is a great technic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would pass it along. If you ever need to have two screens (or windows) rendered using the same function, you'd have to re-architect [aside from the horribleness of using global variables in general].

Edit: And I don't see any point in making it a pointer instead of a reference. Underneath things, it will be the same thing.

Comment: @user1511417 Just added something about "pointer vs. reference".